# How to approach large dataset with shape of (12238470, 211) in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do data analysis on a dataset. In the dataset, there is a parent directory, and in that directory, there are 35 subdirectories and in those subdirectories, there are [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) files of the same structure. I have merged them, and they have been merged successfully, but the shape of the data is (12238470, 211) and when I try to perform basic operations like describe the function or dropping NaN values it gives me this error:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 19.2 GiB for an array with shape (211, 12238470) and data type float64

Here is my code to merge data:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np

folder_path = "Stress-Predict-Dataset-main"
csv_files = glob.glob(f"{folder_path}/**/*.csv", recursive=True)

df_list = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in csv_files]
df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

How to tackle this problem?

Comment: Do these CSV files all have the same columns? You could be generating a bunch of NaNs. What are their individual shapes? You could go through df_list, sum up the shapes and see how that compares with the final shape.

Comment: "I have merged them and they have been Merged Successfully but the shape of the data is (12238470, 211)" Do you think this is the wrong shape? If so, what should the shape be instead? Otherwise, what exactly is the question? Are you looking for a way to reduce the data? Can you use smaller input files? Why exactly do you need to work with a table this big - what problem are you trying to solve, and why would it not work with a smaller input?

Comment: "In the dataset there is a parent directory and in that directory there are 35 subdirectory and in those subdirectories there are csv files of the same structure." In total, how much space does this take up on disk?

Comment: You can use PySpark if you have 12 M rows!

Comment: It is a Raw Data and i have to clean, Rename Columns,  and identify the main columns. They collect the data using a stress detection watch. And its totally in Raw format. This is my University's Assignment and my professor gave this data to me for cleaning and analyzing. and after that put it in the appropriate model for machine learning

Comment: If you frame your (raw)data using Pandas dataframe, which is available in Python as well as bigdata languages e.g, PySpark, Scala, SQL and R, then you can manipulate\clean your data for further actions (ML model) conveniently. @KarlKnechtel addressed good points if you want to resolve the problem of processing large datasets with Python. Pythonic-wisely,`read_csv()` has a parameter\argument so-called `chunksize` that allows you to iterate over chunks of the data. This is typically the approach to working with big files efficiently.

Comment: Better to show a full **Traceback** of the error for further debugging. At the moment, It's not clear whether the problem is how you read data using `pd.read_csv()` or when you concatenate datasets using `pd.concat()`

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset is too large for what your computer can handle. It is recommended to have 5-10x more memory than your dataset size.
You need a tool that break your dataset into chunks, such as [dask](https://www.dask.org/).

Comment: I have used Dask and its still giving me the same error.

Comment: We would need to see the attempt with Dask, in a separate question, after your best attempt to debug the problem, in order to be able to respond to that.

Comment: @Emek This should be a comment unless you extend your solution by providing OP with some scripts within a brief explanation of how to collect datasets of csv files and read\load\frame data via `dask.dataframe.read_csv()`, which you offered as the solution. Nevertheless, it could be a good solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).